# Adding curbs to the edge of a racetrack

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, vertices

Im trying to create a racetrack and want to add curbs to the edge of some corners but dont know how to do this properly.

This is what I have done so far:
I used a path for the track layout, create a plane and used a array and curve modifier so the plane follows the path I created. Thats my racetrack.
Then I sculpted a simple landscape with some altitude variations and used the shrinkwrap modifier on the racetrack so that it follows the landscape altitude.
Now I want to add curbs to certain parts of the racetrack but I don't know how to get them to follow exactly the edge of the track.

I hope you can help me! :)[image: Corner]

New Blender File with Inner Curbs:
[image]

Comment: Hello, if you are ok to apply the Array then you can extrude your road to give it thickness then extrude the curbe where it is needed. If you don't want to apply the Array, you should create another object that will follow the same curve and create the curbs where it is needed. But you can't create the curb in the same object as the road if you want to keep the Array, the Array repeats a mesh.

Comment: Alright, that would work but is there no easy way to simply have an object (my curb) following exactly the edge of the track? 
Because extruding and shaping the curbs manually is probably quite time consuming and at the same time the curbs will then not always have the exact same shape I think.

Comment: again you can make the curb object follow the same curve as the road

Comment: Sure, I know but the problem is, that I have shrink wrapped the road to a 3d surface I created.
On a flat track this works for me as well but not on a sculptured surface, you know what I mean? :)
Let me know if I should share more images or something similar... :)

Comment: i would suggest providing the blend file as it is so we see what you have done and provide solution proposals.

Comment: Apply the Shrinkwrap of your road, duplicate one of its edge, convert to curve, make sure that it is Twist Method > Z-Up, use this curve for the curbs to follow about the same shape?

Comment: I have tried the Method @moonboots described but unfortunately it still does not work. On the outside of corners the curb simply does not follow my created curve at some point and for the inside of the corners the curb gets massively deformed…
 
I have attached my Blender File above and hope you can help me. :)

Thanks!

Comment: The curve is made of 2 curves, it is interrupted at the 10th control point, you need to fill between the 2 curves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your curbs, apply the *Shrinkwrap* of your road, duplicate one of its edge, convert to curve, make sure that it is *Twist Method > Z-Up*, use this curve for the curbs to follow about the same shape.

If I check your file, the problem is that the curve is made of 2 curves, it is interrupted at the 10th control point, you need to fill between the 2 curves then dissolve the vertex:

[image]

As for the inner curbs, I'm afraid there's no magic solution, you could offset it like that:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I didnt saw that... Now its working around the outside of the corner, thank you! But when I do the same for the inside of a corner the curb gets weirdly deformed. Is there a possibility to change that?
Also, how can I set the lower edge of the curb and not the middle to run along the racetrack edge? (Let me know if I should share more images or files for clarification.) :)

Comment: share your new file for the inner curbs because I'm not sure what's the problem, as for the lower edge, move the mesh of the object in Edit mode? Also remove the side faces so that the final object has no inner faces

Comment: Alright, I have shared another file where I tried to add a inside curb, maybe that helps. Thank you for your effort. :)

Comment: I don't think that there's any easy solution, you need to move it so that the faces don't overlap

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!